# Access to alien iframe in chrome extensions on the example of imacros and selenium ide

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, google-chrome-extension, imacros

I'm writing a chrome extension and I'm having trouble accessing an iframe. I ended up googling this issue and all I got was "security policy" and why the iframe can't be accessed.
In manifest.json "all_frames": true does not help:

```
    "permissions": ["tabs","storage","<all_urls>","activeTab"],  
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js", "raschet.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
    ],
```

I found a way to disable web security when turning on the browser: --disable-web-security(+ other settings).
If we do this and go to the site with recaptcha https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo,
after can use the code to click on the captcha:

```
document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0].contentDocument.querySelectorAll("div[class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']")[0].click()
```

Yes it works, but disabling security is not my option.
There are programs for automating work in the browser iMacros and Selenium IDE. These are also extensions with javascript and here they were able to realize focus and click on the iframe.
Exampele iMacros:

```
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:recaptcha-checkbox-border&&ROLE:presentation&&TXT:
```

Exampele Selenium IDE:

```
command: select frame    target: index=0
command: click           target: css=.recaptcha-checkbox-border
```

Is it possible to repeat the same in my extension using JS or Jquery?

Comment: Well, for iMacros, you can always decompile (= simply unzip) the `.xpi` File for the (FF) Add-on and the `imacros.jar` File in it (looking at v8.9.7 for FF ([Download Link](http://download.imacros.net/imacros_for_firefox-8.9.7-fx.xpi))) and "have a look" at how the Functions `checkForFrameChange` (in `MacroRecorder.js`) and `findFrame` (in `MacroPlayer.js`) are coded... // This is how I would "tackle" it if I wanted to achieve the same Functionality... :idea:

Comment: Your content script already runs *inside* the iframe so you don't need to use contentDocument. Simply check `location.href`.

Comment: thank you. My problem was that I did the condition "if" when I was on the main page of the site, but I did not do the same for the iframe. I don't know why I didn't think of this before, it's so simple=)

Comment: You can post *the* Solution / your working Script as "Answer", and even "accept" your own Answer, to make this Thread "useful" for the Community... :idea: